# Installing CORBA orbd-Name Service as Windows Service

Tags: java, service, windows-services, naming, corba

I developed CORBA server/client with use of Java IDL component of Java SE platform.

I want start this application as service on Windows Platform, so i used [Java Service wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) , and installed application as service.

but before starting server, i need to start *orbd.exe* - The CORBA Naming Service from Oracle.

I tried installed this exe as service using `sc create` command from windows.

but when i start this orb service using `sc start`

it gets hangs and throws following error:

```
 [SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Whats wrong with this windows service ?

How do I start the CORBA Naming Service as windows service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could actually run orbd with the Wrapper as well.

Basically you need the following properties in your orbd.conf file:

```
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.app.parameter.1=com.sun.corba.se.impl.activation.ORBD

wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dapplication.home="%JAVA_HOME%"
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dcom.sun.CORBA.activation.DbDir="%JAVA_HOME%"/orb.db
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.CORBA.activation.Port=1049
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.CORBA.POA.ORBServerId=1

wrapper.java.classpath.1=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=%JAVA_HOME%\classes
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/wrapper.jar

wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
wrapper.java.library.path.2=%JAVA_HOME%/bin

wrapper.name=orbd
wrapper.displayname=CORBA Naming Service
```

Once this has been installed as service, you can set for your application a dependency on that service to make sure that orbd is getting started when you run your application.

```
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=orbd
```

(you need to reinstall the application in order to set the dependency)

Hope this helps you out.

cheers

Comment: one question, if i want side effects while starting/stopping service , like deleting any directory, How can i achieve ?
(actually i want to delete the orb.db directory)

Answer (score 3):

You get error 1053 because orbd.exe is not a native Windows Service and can not respond properly to the request to start itself. You will need a "service wrapper" application that can accept the Windows Service commands (start, stop) and take the appropriate actions on your executable (launch, terminate).

[Microsoft's free SRVANY utility](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSrvany) will be adequate if your needs are basic but several more robust commercial alternatives are available too.